# How to print array of LPCTSTR in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, cout

How to print array of LPCTSTR

example

```
LPCTSTR pszValueNames[] = { L"partnerID", L"partnerSubID", L"transactionID" };

for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(pszValueNames) / sizeof(LPCWSTR)); i++)
{
    cout << (*pszValueNames[i]) << endl;
}
```

Above give some numbers which is not real lpctstr values.
When i use wchar_t* and all other basic types it spit good values.

Comment: Looks to me like you just need to get rid of the `*` dereference operator in the `cout` line

Comment: then i get just addresses

Comment: the info here looks useful: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/56526/

Comment: Dont use L with LPCTSTR. Use L with LPCWSTR. Use the _T() macro with LPCTSTR, which will be L or a no-op to match whatever LPCTSTR is for your setup. LPCTSTR is LPCWSTR on Unicode builds and LPCSTR on "ANSI" builds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you get the address printed is that `std::cout` works with `std::string`, which is `char` based.  An `LPCWSTR` is a wide string pointer type, and `cout` has no idea how to display wide strings "as strings".

You should use `std::wcout` to handle a wide string.

`std::wcout << pszValueNames[i] << std::endl`;

Also, your usage of `LPCTSTR` is not correct, even though your program may work.  If you know you're using wide strings, specify `LPCWSTR` anywhere you would have used `LPCTSTR`.  The reason is that `LPCTSTR` is not necessarily a wide string pointer type, depending on the type of build (MBCS or Unicode) that you are using.

So in a nutshell, your string pointer declarations are a hodge-podge of different string types, where some functions may work (if the `LPCTSTR` is a non-wide char pointer), while other string handling functions won't work.

Basically, if you're going to use `LPCTSTR` or `LPTSTR`, then all of your code that handles string or string pointer types should use "build-neutral" types, i.e. use `LPCTSTR`, `TCHAR`, `LPTSTR`, `_T()`, etc.  These types will change seemlessly if you go from an MBCS build to a Unicode build (and vice-versa for whatever reason).

If on the other hand, if you know that the build will only ever be `Unicode`, then `LPCWSTR` and `LPWSTR` should be used throughout your program.  Conversely, if you know and can guarantee that the build will only be MBCS, then use `LPCSTR` and `LPSTR` in your program.

The best thing to do is either use the build-neutral types (`LPCTSTR`, etc.) throughout your application, or change all of these to wide string types (`LPCWSTR`, etc.).  The MBCS builds are becoming very rare these days, so might as well start developing using wide string types, and only use `char` string types in your application when you're interfacing to other functions that rely on `char` based strings.

Comment: Use the _T() macro around literals instead of L if you must use LPCTSTR. It is defined to the appropriate use of L depending on what LPCTSTR is. Google for LPCTSTR for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues. First, you're iterating over the wrong size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(pszValueNames) / sizeof(LPCWSTR)); i++)
//                                                  ^^^^^^^
```

That should be `LPCTSTR`. Or, to avoid this kind of error, just `*pszValueNames`. Or likely the reverse, `LPCWSTR` is the corret type but you declared the array to be `LPCTSTR` instead.

Secondly:

```
cout << (*pszValueNames[i]) << endl;
```

That would dereference the `i`th string - which would print only the first character. To print the whole string you don't need the dereference. Also, you would need to use `wcout` as `cout` does not work with `wchar_t`:

```
wcout << pszValueNames[i] << endl;
```

Comment: No, cout does not work with wchar_t, which tchar is with the ops setup.

Comment: @Barry how to iterate through *pszValueNames?

Answer (score 0):

`std::wcout` was already mentioned, but I'd like to add that this is a nice example of how C++11 features can improve legacy or C-based code – if you can use a C++11 compiler, that is.

In C++11, you can write your loop like this:

```
for (auto const &name : pszValueNames)
{
    std::wcout << name << std::endl;
}
```

No more `sizeof` or dereferencing issues to worry about. And if you later change your array to something like `std::array<std::wstring>` or `std::vector<std::wstring>` or `std::set<std::wstring>`, then the loop will not have to be modified at all (the element type of the container will just have to remain compatible with `std::wcout`).

---

edit: made code example use `const &`

Answer (score -1):

The [] operator accesses the index*sizeof(type) part of the memory after the pointed mem. value, and this operator takes a pointer. You dont need the * there... *pszValue is dereferencing, true, but that is done implicitly here.... so you are actually dereferencing a value...

Quote from MSDN: "Usually, the value represented by postfix-expression is a pointer value, such as an array identifier, and expression is an integral value (including enumerated types). However, all that is required syntactically is that one of the expressions be of pointer type and the other be of integral type."

See the [] operator [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th52k9c8.aspx)